# Elasticsearch running last version no matter what i do

Tags: node.js, elasticsearch, npm, homebrew

So i am trying to run elasticsearch 1.7.x
 I found a way to install it, but nu matter what i do 
curl localhost:9200 shows that i run the last version 6.2.4

Any ideas?[image]

Also
[image]

Comment: Do you have multiple versions running?

Comment: i was, but i stopped the others.Actually this  has been a long day and not much success.. More on "my adventure"  here: https://github.com/itemsapi/curlist/issues/14